# Sql Multiple row merge into single row with specific pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Sql select query which gives merge multiple row into one single row 
using sqlserver 2005 and above
I have two tables ie **(tb_master,tb_tasks)**

```
create table tb_tasks(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
id_tbmaster int NOT NULL,
Tasks nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
)

create table tb_master(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
grade nchar(10) NOT NULL,
name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
task_date datetime NOT NULL,
)

select * from tb_master
id grade name   task_date
1  A     John   2012-02-13 10:40:00.000
2  B     Tom    2012-02-13 10:40:00.000


select tb_tasks
id  id_tbmaster  Tasks
1     1          cooking food.
2     1          Programing 2 hours
3     1          Attending meeting 
4     2          Driving car
5     2          hangout with friends
```

Have tried this query

```
select tasks + ' , ' as 'data()' from tb_tasks for xml path('')
```

Gives Output

```
XML
cooking food ,  Programing 2 hours ,  Attending meeting ,  Driving car ,  hangout with friends ,
```

**I need output like**

```
id Name  grade task_date                tasksDetails
1  John   A    2012-02-13 10:40:00.000  1)cooking food, 2)Programing 2 hours, 3)Attending meeting
2  Tom    B    2012-02-13 10:40:00.000  1) Driving car, 2)hangout with friends
```

Query i tried

```
select a.name,a.task_date,b.tasks =replace(select (CONVERT(VARCHAR,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC)))) + ') ' + tasks + ' , ' as 'data()'
from tb_tasks for xml path(''))
from tb_master a inner join tb_tasks b
on a.id=b.id_tbmaster
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will create requested list of activities per tb_master. Two pointers: one should match ordering in row_number() over() and in query to get consistent results, and number 3 in last row of [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) is number of characters in separator (in this case, ' , '). If you change separator you need to adjust this number.

```
select a.name,a.task_date, b.taskList
from tb_master a
OUTER APPLY
(
  select stuff ((select ' , '
                      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                   OVER(ORDER BY id DESC))
                      + ') ' 
                      + tasks 
                   from tb_tasks b
                  where a.id = b.id_tbmaster
                  order by id desc
                for xml path (''))
               , 1, 3, '') taskList
) b
```

Live demo is at [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf22d/16).